# Защищенные невиртуальные деструкторы базового класса

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, наследование, деструктор

В книге А.Александреску "Стандарты программирования на С++" в 50 совете говорится: "Делайте деструкторы базовых классов открытыми и виртуальными либо защищенными и невиртуальными". Скажите в каких случаях применяются protected невиртуальные деструкторы. В чем польза этого подхода?

Comment: Разве там не приводится мотивация и пример к этому совету?

Comment: Благодарю за минусы. Там приводится пример, но хотелось бы осмотреть на проблему с разных сторон.

Comment: видимо люди не любят Александресу.

Comment: И зря..........

Comment: все нормально. Иначе он бы не пошел создавать D

Comment: Ну, посмотрел - во-первых, там все же первый автор Саттер :), а во-вторых, это писалось еще в 2005 году (русского издания, оригинал, значит, еще раньше...) - так что относиться к советам 15-летней давности я бы (простите за каламбрур) советовал с осторожностью. Но данный совет, мне кажется, актуален..

Comment: ну почему. Вот Саттер сейчас никак не может решится, передавать по значению или константной ссылке и постоянно сотни оговорок.

Comment: Насчет передачи по значению или ссылке тема раскрыта у Мейерса в "Эффективном и современном C++"

Comment: я знаю, у меня есть эта книга. "оговорка" - это не значит, что он случайно говорит неверно. Имеется ввиду, что он очень аккуратен в своих оценках (не "вы должны так делать", а "вы должны рассмотреть возможность")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если класс планируется использовать в качестве базового, т.е. он будет наследоваться - лучше делать деструктор виртуальным, так как может быть удаление через указатель на базовый класс.

```
struct Base
{
    ~Base();
};

struct Derived: public Base
{
    ~Derived();
};


int main()
{
    Base * b = new Derived;
    delete b;
}
```

Так сказать, угадайте с трех раз, какой деструктор вызовется, и будет ли это верное поведение...

Если же вы делаете деструктор не виртуальным, то защититься от такого неверного использования можно, сделав деструктор `~Base()` защищенным - все, такой код вы написать просто не сможете.

Только

```
struct Base
{
protected:
    ~Base() { cout << "~Base\n"; };
};

struct Derived: public Base
{
    ~Derived()  { cout << "~Derived\n"; };
};


int main()
{
    Derived * b = new Derived;
    delete b;
}
```

Но, как и в других вопросах C++ - если бы какой-то совет был не советом, а жестким требованием - он вошел бы в стандарт как запрет. Так что у вас есть выбор, как поступать, и всегда есть ситуации, когда лучше поступить вопреки совету.

Comment: Вот ещё и @Harry спрошу - где, где Вы прочитали, что будет вызван какой то определенный конструктор в этом случае?

Comment: @KoVadim Если деструктор не виртуальный - будет вызван `~Base`, если виртуальный - `~Derived`, за ним `Base`. https://ideone.com/0d3mNR  Что не так? А, вы про описку, что я деструктор конструктором назвал? Спасибо, исправил.

Comment: Простите, а кто минусует? Очень демотивирует задавать вопросы в принципе.

Comment: В данном случае не я. Когда я минусую, я объясняю, почему :)

Comment: не, если почитать стандарт внимательно, то там есть приписка, что если в точке удаления, статический и динамический тип отличается, а виртуального деструктора нет, то будет просто UB.А то что будет "не вызван один из деструкторов"... это просто никто не заморачивается. Но об этом знают единицы... описано в 17 стандарте в главе "12.5 Free store"

Comment: В общем, защищенный деструктор нужен для явного запрета полиморфного создания экземпляров. Верно?

Comment: Честно говоря усилия на ответ потрачены зря, так как в книге такие базовые примеры уже приводятся для пояснения этого совета.

Comment: @KoVadim Ну, я всегда говорю, что я - как в "Петре I" Толстого - "люди не слишком знатные, сие не философы, но более наук практических…" - я пока не встречал, чтоб было иначе; до таких тонкостей я, увы, стандарт не знаю, ориентируюсь больше на книги, учебники - а там как раз пишут, что будет вызываться конструктор базового класса. В принципе, это выглядит очень даже логично...

Comment: @KoVadim 12.5 в стандарте (что 17, что 20) - это Overloaded operators...

Comment: Почему же зря? Кто не читал книгу причастятся к теме ))

Comment: а потом приходит горе-погроммист, который говорит - а в классе наследнике нет "полей" (переменных-членов класса) и ничего странного не будет. А virtual делает класс большим и тяжелым. Поэтому не буду писать

Comment: @KoVadim А вот тут как раз UB и может быть - потому что не вызван деструктор потомка. Но не потому, что не будет вызван никакой из них. По крайней мере, я понимаю ситуацию (пока не нашел нужное место в стандарте) именно так...

Comment: проверил - открывал документ N3337, страница 252. Или это 14 стандарт (взял первый который был  на рабочем столе)

Comment: @Harry Может быть имелось в виду 15.5

Comment: @KoVadim Нашел, в стандарте С++20 это 11.12. Но там слово undefined применяется только один раз, и к освобождению массивов. Что логично - из-за разных размеров элементов базового класса и потомка. Если можно, уточните, где именно про ub в случае несоответствия типов и что может не быть вызван ни один деструктор...

Comment: ещё раз -  документ N3337, страница 252, внизу есть комментарий 118. От него уже текст нужно анализировать.

Comment: @KoVadim В стандартах 17 и 20 этот пункт 5 вообще выброшен...

Comment: я нашел точное место, где я это прочитал. http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.delete - пункты 3 и 11

Comment: @KoVadim Спасибо, почитаю.